# Need "String" as :String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, variables

I need to get my "string" to :string

At the moment I have this and give this:

```
Holidays.between(from, to, ":de")
```

But I need this

```
Holidays.between(from, to, :de)
```

Please Help!

Comment: Where does that `":de"` come from?

Comment: I'm creating ist. I can also create de. Would that be better?

Comment: That would probably fix it, see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using the [Holidays](https://github.com/alexdunae/holidays) gem, just remove the colon from your string, i.e. use `"de"` instead of `":de"`. The gem handles the conversion for you:

```
require 'holidays'

from = Date.civil(2014, 1, 1)
to = Date.civil(2014, 12, 31)

Holidays.between(from, to, "de")
#=> [{:date=>#<Date: 2014-01-01 ((2456659j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, :name=>"Neujahrstag", :regions=>[:de]}, {:date=>#<Date: 2014-04-18 ((2456766j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, :name=>"Karfreitag", :regions=>[:de]}, {:date=>#<Date: 2014-04-21 ((2456769j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, :name=>"Ostermontag", :regions=>[:de]}, {:date=>#<Date: 2014-05-01 ((2456779j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, :name=>"Tag der Arbeit", :regions=>[:de]}, {:date=>#<Date: 2014-05-29 ((2456807j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, :name=>"Christi Himmelfahrt", :regions=>[:de]}, {:date=>#<Date: 2014-06-09 ((2456818j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, :name=>"Pfingstmontag", :regions=>[:de]}, {:date=>#<Date: 2014-10-03 ((2456934j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, :name=>"Tag der Deutschen Einheit", :regions=>[:de]}, {:date=>#<Date: 2014-12-25 ((2457017j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, :name=>"1. Weihnachtstag", :regions=>[:de]}, {:date=>#<Date: 2014-12-26 ((2457018j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, :name=>"2. Weihnachtstag", :regions=>[:de]}]
```

It's unclear where the colon comes from in the first place (looks like a bug) but you should probably fix it there, rather than converting the string.

Comment: New one for me.. that gem..:-)

Comment: +1 for fixing the problem at the source rather than a wonky workaround.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Well I created it with:
rstring=rstring.insert(0, ":")   
rstring=rstring.upcase    
rstring=rstring.swapcase   
rstring=rstring[ 0 .. 2 ]
return rstring

Comment: @MarkThomas I agree with you.. :) Thus I deleted my answer.. It was looking like *waakk* :)

Answer (score 4):

[`String#to_sym`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-to_sym) is what you need call `to_sym` on the string and it becomes a symbol

You need to remove the `:` in the string before converting it to a string(to get the exact symbol required), so the below would do just that

```
Holidays.between(from, to, ":de".sub(":","").to_sym) #=> Holidays.between(from, to, :de)
```

Comment: The string starts with a colon, so `.to_sym` would return `:":de"` - probably not what the OP needs.